# Python regex to return word without double quotes in grouping

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to store values of a string into dictionaries using regex grouping. One of the group must return the text within the double quotes (without the quotes). I have tried using lookarounds to a get the text within quotes but it doesn't work in a group with other things.
The desired result is `{'first_word': 'Remove', 'check': 'this'}`.

```
sampledata= 'Remove "this"'
pattern="""
(?P<first_word>\w*)                #This group is to capture the preceeding word      
(\s)                               #This is a dummy group to capture space
(?P<check>(?<=\")\w*(?=\"))        #This group is to find the word between quotes and return only the word
"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,sampledata,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

Following code groups the data as needed but returns text with quotes so it can't be used.

```
sampledata= 'Remove "this"'
pattern="""
(?P<first_word>\w*)                #This group is to capture the preceeding word      
(\s)                               #This is a dummy group to capture space
(?P<check>["](.*?)["])             #This group is to find the word between quotes and return only the word
"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,sampledata,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the double quotes outside the second group, and it should work:

```py
sampledata = 'Remove "this"'
pattern = r'(?P<first_word>\w*)\s"(?P<check>\w*)"'
for item in re.finditer(pattern, sampledata, re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())  # {'check': 'this', 'first_word': 'Remove'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean how to get a string of inside double quotes?
If so

Input: `'hello "world"'` 
regex: `"(.+)"`

Match 1: `"world"` 
Group 1: `world`

Comment: @Isabella Thank you! This also worked, had to write my group as follows "(?P<quote_word>(.+))"

Comment: @Sqldev: Please be sure to "upvote" this response if you found it helpful.